# Что вызывает ворнинг 'zero as null pointer constant' при использовании макроса Q_OBJECT?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

При создании пустого шаблонного проекта я на ровном получаю предупреждение в автоматически размещенном макросе Q_OBJECT.

```
mainwindow.h:12:5: warning: zero as null pointer constant
qobjectdefs.h:164:5: note: expanded from macro 'Q_OBJECT'
qobjectdefs.h:99:61: note: expanded from macro 'QT_TR_FUNCTIONS'
```

[image: Ворнинг на макросе]

Чем это может быть вызвано и как исправить?

Я использую последнюю версию Qt Creator и довольно старый SDK версии 4.8.6.

Comment: В те временя ещё небыло `nullptr` и `nullptr_t` видимо, а в макросе наверное есть параметры указатели с значениями по-умолчанию в виде `= 0` . Макросами может? с помощью #pragma push/pop отключать генерирование варнингов `zero as null pointer constant` перед Q_OBJECT и включать после Q_OBJECT. Я, к сожалению, не помню, можно ли отключить и какой флаг указывать, а гуглить лень.

Comment: похоже под `Q_OBJECT'ом` в 4.8 есть инициализация указателя в численное значение `0` (ноль, как целое число), в стандарте c++11 уже нужно использовать `nullptr`. Рецепт прост, использовать c++98 в проекте, то есть убрать `CONFIG += console c++11` из файла проекта

Comment: для qt есть собственных макрос Q_NULLPTR, используйте его вместо nullptr

Comment: @asianirish убрал ключ с++11, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: отключите в Qt Creator статический анализ в Plugins

Comment: #include "QMainWindow.h" есть?

Comment: я бы просто отключил предупреждение: добавь `-Wno-zero-as-null-pointer-constant` в `CXXFLAGS`…